# Faild to install nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, nokogiri

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::Command

      Gem::Command.build_args
         ^^^^^^^^^
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
apt-get install openssl ruby-openssl libssl-dev
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries (command that caused this new error. The error before was another, but in essence it was an error when installing nokogiri)
```

Current OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Ruby version: ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x86_64-linux] (installed using RVM)

Rails version: Rails 7.0.4

Comment: Seeing `Gem::Command` fail is really an odd thing, but that is an older (and probably vulnerable?) version of Nokogiri. Try with 1.13.10 which is the now current version.

Comment: The version of Nokogiri that you try to install is about 5 years old. I am not surprised that it doesn't work with the latest version of Ruby anymore. I suggest using the latest version of Nokogiri instead (`1.13.10`). Or if that is not possible, you might need to downgrade Ruby until you find a version that is still supported by that ancient Nokogiri version. Ruby 2.5.0 was just released a few weeks before that old version of Nokogiri. Why do you want to use such an old version of a gem?

Comment: removing rails-3 tag as you are explicitely stating that you're using rails 7